# how to use express-rate-limit in production

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I use `express-rate-limit` package to prevent DDoS and Brute Force attacks on my login page but problem is that i switched to production mode and it needs to add a `store` option, as i read in docs it supports redis store and `memcached` but i use mongoose, so i want to know is it possible to use `express-rate-limit` with mongoose in production mode? I use `connect-mongo` with express session but what should i use with `express-rate-limit`, please provide examples of code. Thank You!

Comment: Alternatively you could use [rate-limiter-flexible package with Mongoose support](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Mongo)

Comment: it seems pretty good library and even expressjs docs recommend, I integrated it in my code but i am confused about this options    `points: 10,
    duration: 1` what does that means? user can perform 10req per sec?

Comment: Yes and No, there is [options description on Wiki](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Options). It depends on how many points are [consumed](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/API-methods#ratelimiterconsumekey-points--1)